# how to disable particular column of grid based on other value of column in extjs

Tags: extjs

This is how I did coding, please help me to disable particular column:

```
listeners: {
    beforeedit: function(obj) {
        debugger;
        var c = obj.record.get('quarterlyreview1');
         if(c==="Approved") {
             var d = obj.record.get('quarterlyprogress1');
             obj.record.cancelEdit();
         }
         // return obj.record.get('status');  
         // you can update the above logic to something else
         // based on your criteria send false to stop editing
    }   
},
```

Comment: With "disable" you mean "deny editing"? What is your ExtJS version?

Comment: ya it mean after the value of quarterlyreview1 is "Approved" , user can't change "quarterlyprogress1" field. 
it's a open source downloaded project so i don't which version its using,  as per requirement i am modifying it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the Documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing-event-beforeedit) if `beforeedit` returns `false` the edit is stopped.
(This code would work for V4 and V5)

```
listeners: {
    beforeedit: function(editor, context, eOpts) {
        debugger;
        var c = context.record.get('quarterlyreview1');
        if(c==="Approved" && (context.colIdx==0 || context.colIdx==1)) {
           return false;
        }
        // return context.record.get('status');  
        // you can update the above logic to something else
        // based on your criteria send false to stop editing
    }   
},
```

Comment: return false;

its work , but it disable whole row, i just want to disable particular cell.

Comment: Do you use rowediting or cellediting plugin? You should use cellediting and the edited code to disable editing in column 1 and 2

Comment: i need one more help.
i want to get the value of column on load of grid and alter that value with string value
like, grid shows rating which comes with integer value, now i want to pop up that integer value to string value
just like if rating 1 then it shows "NME"
if 2 then it shows "UME"

Comment: You can use the [`renderer`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer) config to do that.

Comment: renderer: function(value, meta, record) {
                   debugger;
                      var val = record.get('gemprat');
                      console.log(val); // Here I am always getting status="active". 
                      if (val === '5') {
                       record.set('gemprat', '5');
                      } 
                  }

Comment: You should better create a new post. You could then write the link in a comment here